# Why a strange signed request in Facebook API?

Tags: facebook

I have a facebook application running in canvas page. For last few hours I have started recieving strange signed requests. Earlier I was just getting "Unknown Algorithm" error. But, I made some changes in PHP SDK to record signed requests in error log. Here is what I got:

```
[22-Mar-2012 16:02:27] Unknown algorithm. Expected HMAC-SHA256. Request: !ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½jï¿½ï¿½%Wï¿½myï¿½ï¿½ï¿½B
[22-Mar-2012 16:02:27] Unknown algorithm. Expected HMAC-SHA256. Request: !ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½jï¿½ï¿½%Wï¿½myï¿½ï¿½ï¿½B
[22-Mar-2012 16:03:39] Unknown algorithm. Expected HMAC-SHA256. Request: 2ï¿½$sXEï¿½] ï¿½p-Qï¿½
[22-Mar-2012 16:03:39] Unknown algorithm. Expected HMAC-SHA256. Request: 2ï¿½$sXEï¿½] ï¿½p-Qï¿½
[22-Mar-2012 16:03:41] Unknown algorithm. Expected HMAC-SHA256. Request: ix5ï¿½ï¿½^[Q4ï¿½ï¿½Xï¿½ï¿½Vrï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½
[22-Mar-2012 16:03:41] Unknown algorithm. Expected HMAC-SHA256. Request: ix5ï¿½ï¿½^[Q4ï¿½ï¿½Xï¿½ï¿½Vrï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½
```

I don't understand what is the problem.

And yes, I do not have SSL certificate on my server. Therefore, I am using Social-Server page, which has an iframe that displays my unencrpted page. Can that be a problem?